# text over a border in css3

Tags: css, border, effect

I'm curious. It's more for fun and tips but do you know if I can deal with a property to position the text in the middle.

I have post code on  JS bin (refresh if CSS don't open) : http://jsbin.com/3/uhumok/edit?html,css,live

**HTML :**

```
<a class="one" href="#">Hi !</a>
```

**CSS :**

```
a {
    display:block;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    -moz-border-radius:50px;
    border-radius:50px;

    border-width:50px;
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);

    -webkit-transition:0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition:0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:0.2s ease;
    transition:0.2s ease;
}

a:hover {
    border-width:0;
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -ms-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.5s;
    transition-duration:0.5s;
}

a.one {border-style:solid;}
```

I think this is impossible without `:after` or `:before`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add another tag inside the `<a>`? If so, you can absolute position this inner tag to achieve that: http://jsbin.com/3/uhumok/6/edit?html,css,live.

Answer (score 0):

if you make the color:#000 and add padding-top:50px to :hover, the text will almost stay in the same place. i didn't save the example because i didn't see a save option. if you used :before/:after the text would be absolutely positioned so idk why you don't want to use them;